# How do I add to this simple while loop script?

Tags: shell-script

I've got this simple script that will echo "Nope, try again." if the user enters anything other than "red", and then keep asking. How do I add to the script to echo "That's right!" if the user does enter "red", and then stop?

```
echo -n "What is my favorite color?  "
read favorite
while [ "$favorite" != "red" ]; do
echo "Nope, try again."; read favorite
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your loop ends if the user enters the string `red`?  That means that when the loop ends, `$favorite` will be `red` (or the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and `$favorite` would be empty).

The simplest change you could do to your code (ignoring that the user could exit the loop with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) would therefore be to output the string at the end of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf 'What is my favorite color? ' >&2
read favorite
while [ "$favorite" != "red" ]; do
echo "Nope, try again."; read favorite
done

echo "That's right!"
```

I've also done away with `echo -n` and replaced it with a more standard `printf` call that additionally prints to standard error (like prompts should be printed). If you're using `bash`, you could use `read -p 'Enter color: ' color` to both prompt the user with a question and read the color in one go.

If you want to solve it properly, do a loop with input validation the way it's usually done:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    printf 'Enter color: ' >&2
    read color

    if [ "$color" = "red" ]; then
        break
    fi

    echo 'Nope, try again'
done

echo "That's correct!"
```

Notice how the loop now is infinite and only terminates via the `break` statement?  This stops the user from breaking out of the loop with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and requires them to instead enter the correct input. Upon entering the *wrong* input, the user is additionally prompted for the color again.

This guarantees that after the loop, `$color` would be `red`.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I didn't think of just adding echo after the loop. One other question: How do I ignore letter case in the "red" response? (ie, accept Red or RED or red)

Comment: @Raucko You would use `if [ "$color" = "red" ] || [ "$color" = "RED" ]; then` if you want to test for both `red` and `RED`. Or, if you use `bash`, `if [[ $color == [rR][eE][dD] ]]; then`, or `if [[ ${color,,} == "red" ]]; then` to lowercase the inputted string before comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta take your logic inside the while loop -

```
while true; do
  echo -n "What is my favorite color?  "
  read favorite
  if [[ $favorite == "red" ]]; then
     echo "That's Right"
     exit 0
  fi
  echo "No, try again."
done
```